# Parsing and replacing values in an irregular multiline text file with powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a text file that is used for a batch email job.  Currently I have to manually go through the file and set the flag (eomm:) on certain entries so that the email is NOT sent.  This file can contain hundreds of rows.  Here is a snapshot of the file:

```
reci:
reci:
subj:
body:
body: 
eomm:yes
reci:
reci:
subj:
body:Your request for...
body: 
eomm:no
reci:
reci:
subj:
body:Your request for...
body:app_name
body:
eomm:yes
reci:
reci:
subj:
body:Your request for...
body: 
eomm:yes
reci:
reci:
subj:
body:Your request for...
body: 
body: 
body: Please note that...
body:
body:Because the application you selected requires an install,...
eomm:yes
```

So, each email starts with 2 'reci:' entries, 1 'subj:' entry, 2 or more 'body:' entries, and one 'eomm:' entry, in that order.  **Currently I have to find entries that only have 2 'body:' entries but have a 'eomm:' value set to 'yes' and change it to 'no'.**
This is what I need to automate.

So far I have a script that loops through this looking for this pattern but only finds the last match.  (I had the results going to an output file to verify what it was actually doing).  Here's what I have so far:

```
$logfile = gc ./cstemail.txt
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $logfile.count; $i++) {
    if ($logfile[$i] -match 'subj:') {
      if ($logfile[$i + 1] -match 'body:') {
        if ($logfile[$i + 2] -match 'body:') {
            if ($logfile[$i + 3] -match 'eomm:yes') {
                    $logfile[$i + 3].replace('eomm:yes','eomm:no')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My final script needs to be able to locate these lines and replace the 'eomm:yes' with 'eomm:no'.  Seems like it should work with what I have but the replace function doesn't work.  I also tried the following with no luck:

```
$logfile[$i + 3] -replace 'eomm:yes','eomm:no'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, except that you are not assigning the new string to anything. The replace returns a **new** string (strings are immutable).

```
$logFile[$i + 3] = $logfile[$i + 3].replace('eomm:yes','eomm:no')
```

You must also write the contents of the array back out to a file.

```
$logFile > YourFileName.txt
```

Comment: You nailed it.  Thanks dugas!  I knew I was close. :)

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't a Powershell-specific solution, you could implement the following multiline regular expression replacement:

Find:

```
((reci:\r\n){2}subj:\r\n(body:.*\r\n){2}eomm:)(yes)
```

Replace:

```
$1no
```

It performs correctly on [this online regex tester](http://gskinner.com/RegExr) using your sample input.

I wrote up a sample script to illustrate how to do this:

```
$entireFile = [Io.File]::ReadAllText(".\input.txt")
$nl = [Environment]::NewLine

$newLines = $entireFile -replace "(?m)((reci:${nl}){2}subj:${nl}(body:.*${nl}){2}eomm:)(yes)", '$1no'
$newLines > "output.txt"

# Show differences
compare-object -referenceObject $(gc "input.txt") -differenceObject $(gc "output.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks neontapir.  I tried getting your example to work for me but no luck.  I'm pretty new to the more complex regex though.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working script. It took me a few times to realize that the line endings were different on the online regex tester than on my Windows machine.